# Facebook Graph API ERROR

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am implementing facebook graph api to get the user details such as firstname, email etc.

below is my code.

```
$nvpreq = "access_token=160370244010460|b8eba6c19f01b271ef0c682e-100000018108668|q50nk4_LpXvCdnpgiI-jyBPrzCM"; 

$Curl_Session = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/100001573561119');
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$httpResponse = curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
curl_close ($Curl_Session);
```

But i receive below error

```
"type":"GraphMethodException","message":"Unsupported post request."}}1
```

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: Could you please format the code so that it's easier to read? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The access token should be passed using the GET method, not POST. Just append it to your URL and it should work fine!

Comment: Thanks the issue has been sorted now