# Creating events with the Facebook Graph API

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create an event through the Facebook Graph API and I keep getting an "Invalid Parameter" error. I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
FB.api('/me/events','post',{access_token: accessToken, name: name, start_time: startTime},function(retVal) {});
```

This is the response:

> code 100
>
> message "(#100) Invalid parameter"
>
> type "OAuthException"

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: what access_token are you posting ? if you login using the sdk ( FB.login ) with the correct permissions it shouldn't be necessary to post the access_token along

Comment: I'm currently using the access token from my user session, but I have tried the token from my app, which didn't work, and I've also tried it without a token at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here's the deal. The access_token value has to be passed as a GET instead of a POST with the rest of the parameters. So when I changed the FB call to this:

```
FB.api('/me/events?access_token=' + accessToken,'post',{name: name, start_time: startTime},function(retVal) {});
```

It worked beautifully.  I found the answer on a similar question here ([Facebook Graph API ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751419/facebook-graph-api-error)), so many thanks to Bartek for solving my problem without even knowing it!